Why is USB device path retrieved via PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A different from MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK?
I'm creating custom controller application for USB cameras.
The application can be separated into 2 parts - HWDetector and Controller.
First part is hardware detection, it detects connection/disconnection of the hardware and eventually notifies second part of the application. For this I have used similar solution to this. Basically I have non-visible window whose message handler also receives notification for device changes (using RegisterDeviceNotification).
Second part is controlling the camera via Media Foundation. One of it's responsibility is to detect (after notification from the first part), whether added USB camera is suitable for the system based on the configuration. Simply put, there is a function which determines whether the camera supports configured format (MJPEG, etc..):
void CheckIfDeviceSupportsEncoding(const std::string &symbolicLink, EncodingEnum encoding)
{
    IMFActivate** devices = nullptr;
    uint32_t count = 0;
    MFEnumDeviceSources(m_attributes.get(), &devices, &count);
    
    IMFActivate* searchedDevice = nullptr;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        IMFActivate* device = devices[i];
        LPWSTR devicePath = nullptr;
        device->GetAllocatedString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK, &devicePath, nullptr);
        
        if (WindowsAPI::WStringToString(devicePath) == symbolicLink) { // simplified, but I'm using case insensitive compare
            searchedDevice = device;
        }
        
        if (searchedDevice == nullptr || searchedDevice != device) {
            WindowsAPI::SafeRelease(&devices[i]);
        }
    }
    
    //... creation of media source, checking whether device supports encoding, cleanup ...
}

However, device path retrieved from HWDetector using PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A is not equivalent to the one retrieved using device->GetAllocatedString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK, &devicePath, nullptr);. Here is comparison of those two:
"\\\\?\\USB#VID_0C00&PID_AEAE&MI_00#6&2d77a22d&2&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\\GLOBAL"
"\\\\?\\usb#vid_0c00&pid_aeae&mi_00#6&2d77a22d&2&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\\global"

I have read something about device indentification strings, but I haven't found out the reason why the dbcc_classguid does not match with GUID obtained via Media Foundation's MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK.
Currently, my solution parses those two strings and compares their product and vendor ID, but I would rather not to parse them, as the original documentation says I shouldn't.
Why those two doesn't match? Is there a better approach/how to correctly compare those identification strings?
Thank you for your help!

You query for 2 different interfaces: KSCATEGORY_CAPTURE and KSCATEGORY_VIDEO_CAMERA so and result is different. 2 different symbolic links (despite it can point to the same device, which implement both interfaces )

@RbMm Thank you! Haven't noticed that. That solved my issue.
